# Extending the SCIM schema with wso2is 4.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to wso2is, and I'm trying to add the extended schema to SCIM user management as described in http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Extensible+SCIM+User+Schemas+With+WSO2+Identity+Server

I was able to successfully enable the extended schema in the configuration file, do the claims mapping and even successfully create an user with extended claims, but the problem is that when I request the user information back through the /User/ or /Users endpoints, I can't find a way to have the extended attributes included in the result, which always contains only the standard SCIM schema attributes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mapped your claims to http://wso2.org/claims dialect. But you need to map those claims under the urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0  dialect. Once you map these under the urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0 dialect, GET request populate the extended claims as well.

Regards,
Venura